# Regex: If pattern exists, match another pattern

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
tel:+12344390212344943887034;abcd=0032;trunk-context=123abcdef@test.com;user=phone
```

It has to match tel:, then number must have + in front. Whitespace allowed between : and +
If the letter E is in number than it must be followed by 4 digits then 49 eg E123449. (E is not always present)

Using this regex:

```
^((tel)(:\s*)?\+(E)?\d{4}49*)
```

But it allows +E123441, +E123442 etc which are invalid

There seems to be a problem with 4* numbers.
What do I need to update to?

Comment: replace `(E)?\d{4}49*` with `(E\d{4}49|\d+)`. This may help

Comment: What do you want to match if E is not present? Provide examples for both cases.

Comment: Cheers blacksmith, looks good

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?:tel)(?::\s*)?\+(?:(E)?|\d)(?(1)\d{4}49\d+|\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/12)

See more about conditions in regex [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

**Explanation:**

```
(?(1)\d{4}49\d+|\d+)
```

Match the chars using the regex in the first part `\d{4}49\d+` only if the 1st group exists otherwise match all the digits using the regex in the second part `\d+`.